# event handler for multiple controls vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, event-handling

AM trying trap specific events for some controls on a form. i tried this, but its not fireing the events

```
 For Each ctrl As Control In pnlGeneral.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
                AddHandler (DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).CheckedChanged), AddressOf Control_Changed
            ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
                AddHandler (ctrl.TextChanged), AddressOf Control_Changed
            ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is NumericUpDown Then
                AddHandler (DirectCast(ctrl, NumericUpDown).ValueChanged), AddressOf Control_Changed
            End If

        Next
```

Can anyone help me with the fix?

EDIT

I found out that am placing the control in multiple controls, on the form is a panel, inside the panel is different groupbox, these group boxes have the controls am trying to trap their events

Comment: Where do you execute this code?

Comment: Look in the Output window.  Do you see a "first chance exception"?

Comment: Just for the heck of it place that code in the Shown event.  Do all of those events have the same signature?

Comment: Your code works-- I've tested it.

Comment: @LarsTech did you test with the controls NumericUpDown, Checkbox and textbox

Comment: @dbasnett is there any difference between placing it in the Form_load and show event?

Comment: @Smith I created a panel called pnlGeneral, put a CheckBox, NumericUpDown, and a TextBox on it, copied your code to the Form_Load event, added a ListBox to the side, and then in the Control_Changed procedure, just did ListBox1.Items.Add(sender.ToString) and it fired on all those change events.

Comment: @Smith See update to my original post.

Comment: @dbasnett does this work too `Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)`, i didn't know, i didn't try it because i thought it was my answer you copied bac, i will mark it as the answer then

Comment: If you tried it and it works then it does.  No I did not copy your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So as Lars said it does appear to work.

**edited in place to account for controls in containers**

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(Me, True)
    Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
        If TypeOf ctrl Is CheckBox Then
            AddHandler (DirectCast(ctrl, CheckBox).CheckedChanged), AddressOf Control_Changed
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is TextBox Then
            AddHandler (ctrl.TextChanged), AddressOf Control_Changed
        ElseIf TypeOf ctrl Is NumericUpDown Then
            AddHandler (DirectCast(ctrl, NumericUpDown).ValueChanged), AddressOf Control_Changed
        End If
        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Control_Changed(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    Debug.WriteLine(sender.ToString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form_Activate(Byval sender As Object,Byval e as System.EventArgs) Handles Form.Activate

    Dim Ctrl as System.Windows.Forms.Control

    For Each Ctrl in Me.Controls
    If Typeof Ctrl Is System.Windows.Forms.TextBox then
    AddHandler Ctrl.GotFocus, AddressOf TextFocus
    AddHandler Ctrl.LostFocus, AddressOf TextUnfocus
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub TextFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    CType(sender,System.Windows.Forms.TextBox).BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub

Private Sub TextUnfocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.TextBox).BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```